# How to output get-content to array in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have the following code:

```
get-content C:\file.txt | Foreach{($_ | Select-String "$" -all).Matches | measure | select count}
```

I want to find the number of $ in the file on each line, which works successfully, I am given a tabled count of the number of each character per line. However, I want to output each as a value to an array and perform an arithmetic operation on the count. As it stands everything I've tried has given me a multidimensional array in stead of an array of integers.
For example I've tried

```
$counts = @(get-content C:\ampersand.txt | Foreach{($_ | Select-String "&" -all).Matches | measure | select count} )
```

but that just spits out a multidimensional array which I can't perform an arithmetic operation on

Comment: This thing I see wrong of the top of my head is that your not returning an integer array but an object array with a count parameter. `| select  -expand count` help? Do you have an example of what you are trying to do with the output?

Comment: I want to output and be able to  do something like

foreach($count in $counts){$count %= 2}

Comment: Ok. that probably is what I said then. Try the code in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just one of the PowerShell gotcha's. `$Counts` is not an integer array but an object array with a count property.

```
get-content C:\file.txt | Foreach{($_ | Select-String "$" -all).Matches | measure | select-object -ExpandProperty count}
```